# JSON data not being displayed

Tags: jquery, json

I am using data that's in a csv file to display it using JSON.  I can see it in the alert, but not in the html.  Also, I tried to create an associative array to make it easier to refer to through Jquery, but it's not being passed that way.

```
 <?php 
 if (($handle = fopen('upload/05-22-2012-1-43-28BEN-new.csv'. '', "r")) !== FALSE) {
       while (($row_array = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ","))) {
            while ($val != '') {
                foreach ($row_array as $key => $val) {
                        $row_array[] = array_combine($key, trim(str_replace('"', '', $val)));
                        }
                }
            $complete[] = $row_array;
            //print_r($row_array);

            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        echo json_encode($complete);

 ?>
```

HTML

```
 <body>    
      <div id="showdata"></div>

 </body>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('WF-XML.php', function(data) {
        alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
        //alert (data.item1+" "+data.item2+" "+data.item3); //further debug
        $('#showdata').html(data);
    });
});
```

Results

```
 [["11704","1611704","BENV1072"],["11703","1611703","BENV1073"]]
```

Comment: Please read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for what argument type to pass into the html() method.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you call [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with two strings. Do you?

Comment: I was trying to create an associative array.

Comment: Is $row_array not already associative, as you loop through it with a foreach-as-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to stringify your object using JSON.stringify, also .html() method does not escape the string - try using .text() instead.

I've created a simple fiddle for testing - http://jsfiddle.net/E9KTy/

Comment: Thanks! Thank worked!  How would I loop through the results and display them in an html formatted way?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Could you please update your post and add an example JSON string that I can use for testing?

Comment: Also, my results are being displayed like this: [["11704","1611704","BENV1072"],["11703","1611703","BENV1073"]] Without the sqwiggled brackets. How would I refer to them in an array?

Comment: OK, so basically you have a two dimensions array and want to loop through the second dimension? If this is the case then check out the following example - http://jsfiddle.net/E9KTy/2/

Comment: What if I only wanted to print the data that's in the second position of the array?